# Write script to generate report on every Thursday

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh, x-server

On every Thursday we have to send the report like below for 18 servers

Account: swebwpsp
Server name: nykpsr17896
Disk space usage: 70 % (we use df -kh command)
Date: 20-09-2018

Similarly we have 18 servers are there

Can we automate this?

Comment: Are you just waiting to get a crontab ready to go? Maybe you need to do some research before asking!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cron](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) to run a task periodically, including once a week on a specific day of the week. You can write a script to query a list of servers and then save the report.

Run `crontab -e` as the user you want to run your task as. For example:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *     command to be executed
  0  0  *  *  thu  /path/to/your/script
```

An example of script which reads a list of servers and executes a command over ssh:

```
#!/bin/sh
report="report-$(date -I)" # report file
servers="servers.txt"      # file containing a list of hosts
command="df -hk"           # command to execute at remote host

exec 1>$report             # redirect output to report file
exec 2>&1                  # stderr to stdout

while IFS= read -r server; do
    echo "querying server: ${server}"
    ssh -n "${server}" -- "${command}" 
done < $servers
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please provide the sample script